# Android Debugging with Eclipse on my HTC Evo: Augh!

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I've turned on USB debugging.  I have the latest HTC Sync and android SDK components.  I'm using Eclipse 3.5 on windows XP.  I'm running Android 2.2, and am asking for 2.1 as the minimum in the debugger.  I work in Eclipse/Java just about every day, and have for several years.  I'm even writing an Eclipse plugin at work as I type this.... neither Eclipse nor Java are new to me by quite a stretch.

When I start a debug session for the "Skeleton App" sample project, I can see my Evo, and the activity launches (with any freshly saved changes), should I select it.

*BUT*: my breakpoints are ignored<strike>, and *logCat* doesn't see my app's output</strike>(see comments below).

**W**hat a **T**errible **F**ailure (As the api so artfully puts it)!

(oh look... a formatting bug.  Looks like bold text wants **white space** to function properly 10/15/2010)

I have tried different android connection types (charge only, disk drive, HTC Sync, and USB tethering) to no avail.  I've tried Eclipse 3.6 for a bit before yielding to the inevitable and reinstalling 3.5.  I monkeyed with the emulator for a while but ran into a different set of issues (I had to reboot the emulator every time I wanted to make a change... Eclipse's auto-build/hot-swap has me spoiled).

Is there something I can add to (or remove from) the `AndroidManifest.XML` to deal with this?  A magical incantation perhaps?  Must I pray towards San Jose three times a day on a rug woven from kernel gurus' vast and scruffy beards?  Is my Evo not Kosher?  Must I be "sky clad" while debugging?  Shall I teach my laptop to genuflect?

Comment: Okay, the debuggable flag seems to have resolved my logCat issues with Log.d(), but I still cannot connect a debug session:  ***[2010-10-16 09:36:48 - Grr] Launch error: Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.***

Comment: Still unable to connect a debug session.  Further up in the logs I found an exception (I'm using a different machine or I'd post the stack trace), something about "bind isn't a supported protocol"?!  The machine has a wireless connection, but I don't see how that would change the available protocols...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you followed all the points from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) ? You need to set a flag in the manifest and also enable debugging on the actual device.

Comment: I'd turned on debugging on the device, but missed the flag.  THANK YOU!  You'd think eclipse would automagically add that when you start a debug session for the app.  Guess not.  Feature Request!

Comment: Oops... spoke too soon.  The debuggable flag got the logCat thing working, but I'm still not able to connect a debug session... I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to the debugger issue.  Google comes through again:

I found an IOException hiding in my DDMS log:  Address family not supported by protocol family: bind

Googling for that, plus "android" turned up the [answer in the first link](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5371539).  Windows Vista specifies "localhost" as ":::1", but android doesn't really support IPv6 yet.  Changing localhost to "127.0.0.1" resolved the issue.

This is defined in c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts.  I needed to run notepad "as admin" in order to save the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I also have an HTC Evo 4G, and have been having the same debugging problems with Eclipse Helios (3.6). I just learned to use this debugger a day or two ago, and it worked fine. I noticed that there was an automatic Android OS update in the last day or two, also. Perhaps this is just a coincidence.

BUT - my beard was indeed scruffy yesterday, as you suggest, and the debugger was working. I've since shaved. Bad idea, apparently.

Butt seriously - I powered down both Evo and computer (HP running Vista), removed battery from both, then started over. Same result, that is, no debugging.

Comment: First tip:  DO NOT USE HELIOS.  There are quite a few issues with the android plugin.  I tried using it anyway for a bit, and gave up.  Yes, you'll have to reinstall all your plugins in the Galileo folder.  Good news: they coexist nicely (or maybe that's my problem?)